# DateTime precision in NHibernate and support for DateTime2 in NHibernate SchemeExport

Tags: nhibernate, datetime, fluent-nhibernate, timestamp, granularity

I am then using Fluent NHibernate and its automapping feature to map the the following simplified POCO class:

```
public class Foo
{    
public virtual int Id { get; set; }    
public virtual datetime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }    
}
```

The CreatedDateTime field will map to a SQL DateTime by default.  However if I do a test to check that the entity is being created correctly it fails.  This is because the precision of the DateTime field is not maintained through to the SQL database.  I undersatnd the reason behind this to be that a MS SQL Server DateTime can only hold milisecond precision by rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx).  For this reason NHibernate truncates the miliseconds when saving to the store.  This results in my test failing when checking that the fields where persisted correctly as my .NET DateTime holds its miliseconds but the DateTime retrived after the save has lost its miliseconds and therefore the two are not truely equal.

To overcome this problem I have added the following mapping to the Foo object:

```
public class FooMap : IAutoMappingOverride<Foo>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Foo> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Map(f => f.CreatedDateTime).CustomType("datetime2");     
    }
}
```

I understand that this mapping makes NHibernate persist the CreatedDateTime to a SQL type of datetime2, which can store the full precision that a .NET DateTime can.
This works a treat and the test now passes.

However with one pass comes another fail: My test that checks the schema export now fails with the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException : Dialect does not support DbType.DateTime2
Parameter name: typecode
```

with a stack trace of:

```
at NHibernate.Dialect.TypeNames.Get(DbType typecode)
at NHibernate.Dialect.Dialect.GetTypeName(SqlType sqlType)
at NHibernate.Mapping.Column.GetDialectTypeName(Dialect dialect, IMapping mapping)
at NHibernate.Mapping.Table.SqlCreateString(Dialect dialect, IMapping p, String defaultCatalog, String defaultSchema)
at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.GenerateSchemaCreationScript(Dialect dialect)
at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport..ctor(Configuration cfg, IDictionary`2 configProperties)
at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport..ctor(Configuration cfg)
```

The code uses the NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport object to call the Execute method.

I am using Fluent v1 and NHibernate v2.1.

I have also tried mapping my `DateTime` to a TimeStamp but couldn't even get the mapping working as the insert fails stating:

Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column. Use `INSERT` with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a `DEFAULT` into the timestamp column.

Does anyone know either how to get the SchemeExport working with a `datetime2` OR how to get timestamp mapping working for a `datetime` property?

Comment: NHibernate does not truncate the milliseconds because of sql-server. Check my answer

Comment: Specifying a customer time works for me as well as long as I use SQL Server. Thank you for that! It fails with PostgreSQL, though, with "System.InvalidCastException : Can't cast DateTime2 into any valid DbType"

Answer (score 33):

Actually the NHibernate reference states that the DateTime nhibernate type will store the .NET DateTime as an SQL datetime truncated at the second level (no millisecond granularity)

As such it provides the `Timestamp` NHibernate type (`type="Timestamp"` in the mapping) which will store a .NET `DateTime` as an SQL `datetime` without truncation. Note here that an SQL `timestamp` datatype is **not** needed and will infact break if you have more than one `timestamp` column in one table. It's thus important to differentiate between the `sql-type` and `type` attributes in the NHibernate mapping.

Additionally, note that if you are working with filters, the same rule applies at the filter definition: If you specify a `DateTime` parameter, the parameter's value will be truncated without milliseconds.

Check out [chapter 5.2.2. Basic value types](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html), [Table 5.3 System.ValueType Mapping Types](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#d0e4668).

Comment: any idea how to tell NHibernate not to truncate that?

Comment: @asbjornu no, it is not NHibernate's limitation. To clarify: The SQL "Timestamp" type is allowed only once per table. The NHibernate "Timestamp" type is allowed as many as you want. Get your facts straight before downvoting

Comment: @Jaguar, sorry, I must have misread something when I read about this the other day. Please edit your entry so I can change my downvote to an upvote.

Comment: @asbjornu what is the required clarification? The second paragraph states clearly the type-map :s

Comment: @Jaguar, nothing *needs* to be clarified, it's just that the answer must be edited for me to change my vote. :-/ Perhaps you can add information about "timestamp" being a type in SQL Server and shouldn't be confused with `type="Timestamp"` in NHibernate?

Comment: @asbjornu done, although the second paragraph actually stated what you want me to re-write.

Comment: Very helpful - I had no idea NHibernate performed this truncation at the millisecond level + 1

Comment: @Jaguar, I've upvoted and added a more elaborate explanation of SQL Server's `timestamp` limitations. Thanks!

Comment: @asbjornu aha so the mystery is solved but i can't help to notice that your addendum it is also partially incorrect since you can only ever have at most 1 timestamp column in sql server.

Comment: @Jaguar, the fact that you can have at most 1 timestamp column in SQL Server is what I was trying to express. If you have any ideas for a better wording, please just edit your post. :)

Answer (score 6):

For anyone looking to actually keep the nanosecond part of the date, you'll have to use DateTime2 as the sql-column type as well as the Nhibernate DateTime2 type.

Here's my convention for setting this up (using fluent)

```
public class DateTimeConvention : IPropertyConvention, IPropertyConventionAcceptance
{

    public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IPropertyInspector> criteria)
    {
        criteria.Expect(x => x.Type == typeof(DateTime) || x.Type == typeof(DateTime?));
    }
    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        instance.CustomSqlType("DateTime2"); //specify that the sql column is DateTime2
        instance.CustomType("DateTime2"); //set the nhib type as well
    }
}
```

And to activate the convention:

```
 var v = Fluently.Configure()
         .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
         .ConnectionString(d => d.FromConnectionStringWithKey("connstring"))
         .ShowSql())
         .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<IRepository>()
         .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<IRepository>()) //this adds your convention
         .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Using this you'll get to keep nanoseconds when storing your datetimes.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem with a CreatedDate audit field on my business classes. I worked around it by setting the time using the value from a utility method. Hope this helps.

```
     /// <summary>
    /// Return a DateTime with millisecond resolution to be used as the timestamp. This is needed so that DateTime of an existing instance
    /// will equal one that has been persisted and returned from the database. Without this, the times differ due to different resolutions.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private DateTime GetTime()
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var ts = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second, now.Millisecond, DateTimeKind.Local);
        return ts;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Jamie, so do you just use this method in your testing?
I tried you method, however as it still uses milliseconds, I have the same error.  Are you supposed to be using 0 instead of now.Millisecond?

Comment: Good question, I was thinking the same thing when I posted it. I need to write some more tests to check, but replacing now.Millisecond with 0 should do the trick.

Comment: Yes it does, cheers.  If all else fails I could go back to sql datetimes and use this solution as I probably don't actually need this level of precision.

However it would still be great to see how you can preserve the exact precision for future refernce.

Comment: Downvoted because the above is just cloning the DateTime.Now. See reference to .NET here which states that the DateTime.Now already returns this as a local DateTime. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(VS.96).aspx

Comment: No it isn't. DateTime.Now has resolution to 1 tick (100ns) and this method creates a DateTime with millisecond resolution which I can round-trip to a SQL Server datetime. I tried DateTime.Now first and wrote this method to solve a specific problem, as I explained in the code comment.

Answer (score 0):

In my domain it is acceptable to lose the milliseconds from datetimes in SQL Server.  I therefore allow a tolerance in my persistance testers using this static helper (nunit implementation):

```
public static class AssertDateTime
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks that the DateTimes are no more than second apart
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Expected"></param>
    /// <param name="Actual"></param>
    public static void AreWithinOneSecondOfEachOther(DateTime Expected, DateTime Actual)
    {
        var timespanBetween = Actual.Subtract(Expected);

        if (timespanBetween > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
            Assert.Fail(string.Format("The times were more than a second appart. They were out by {0}. Expected {1}, Actual {2}.", timespanBetween, Expected, Actual));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my optimistic locking worked out using the below:
(using datetime2).

Note, I used the name (and case of the datatype-name) from here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dbtype.aspx
"DateTime2" is in my mapping code (under CustomType) and not the Sql Server data-type-case ("datetime2").  I'm not sure if that makes a difference but I wanted to point it out.

Fluent Mapping:

```
public class DogBreedMap : ClassMap<DogBreed>
{
    public DogBreedMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.DogBreedUUID).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
        OptimisticLock.Version();
        Version(x => x.Version)
           .Column("MyTimestamp").CustomType("DateTime2");
    }
}




public partial class DogBreed
{

    public DogBreed()
    {
        CommonConstructor();
    }

    private void CommonConstructor()
    {
        this.Version = DateTime.MinValue; /*I don't think this is necessary*/
    }

    public virtual Guid? DogBreedUUID { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime Version { get; set; }
}
```

The Sql Server column is created at:

```
[MyTimestamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL
```

And my basic tests work and I (correctly) receive an exception like this (when someone else has updted the row)

Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [DogBreed#abcabc1d-abc4-abc9-abcb-abca01140a27]

```
at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Check(Int32 rows, Object id, Int32 tableNumber, IExpectation expectation, IDbCommand statement)
```

at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Update(Object id, Object[] fields, Object[] oldFields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Int32 j, Object oldVersion, Object obj, SqlCommandInfo sql, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.UpdateOrInsert(Object id, Object[] fields, Object[] oldFields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Int32 j, Object oldVersion, Object obj, SqlCommandInfo sql, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Update(Object id, Object[] fields, Int32[] dirtyFields, Boolean hasDirtyCollection, Object[] oldFields, Object oldVersion, Object obj, Object rowId, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Action.EntityUpdateAction.Execute()
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable)
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list)
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions()
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource session)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush()
   at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Commit()