# ActiveRecord/NHibernate DateTime problem

Tags: c#, nhibernate, datetime, postgresql, castle-activerecord

I'm using `ActiveRecord`/`NHibernate` for ORM mapping in my project with PostgreSQL 8.4.
I have following issue

For class mapping

```
 [ActiveRecord(Schema = "public", Table = "test_bean")]
 public class TestBean
 {
  [PrimaryKey(SequenceName = "test_bean_id_seq", Generator = PrimaryKeyType.Sequence)]
  public int ID { get; set; }

  [Castle.ActiveRecord.Property("time")]
  public DateTime Time { get; set; }
 }
```

and SQL DDL

```
CREATE TABLE test_bean
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  time timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT test_bean_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

When I save objects in DB ActiveRecord/NHibernate will truncate/ignore milliseconds component of `DateTime` field. I have made some research and found this [post](http://www.mostlyclean.com/post/2007/11/Increasing-DateTime-storage-precision-in-Nhibernate-%28and-Castle-ActiveRecord%29.aspx) but I would prefer solution that doesn't require writing custom type.

Comment: BTW you might want to make those properties virtual to enable lazy loading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Timestamp` NHibernate type ([similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033630/datetime-precision-in-nhibernate-and-support-for-datetime2-in-nhibernate-schemeex), [docs](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-types-basictypes))

```
[Property(ColumnType = "Timestamp")]
DateTime Time {get;set;}
```