# DateTime.Now in C# to yield Datetime2(3) in SQL Server datatype

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, t-sql, c#-4.0, datetime-format

I tried several ways to retrieve `datetime2(3)` equivalent from C# code but in vain.

One of them is as follows.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
```

I need the following format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.FFF
```

But from the above code, I got the following result

```
6/19/2012 11:15:08 PM
```

When I tried the following way,

```
 string myTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff");
 DateTime dd = Convert.ToDateTime(myTime);
```

it is throwing following error

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I need the date in `datetime2(3)` format only instead you can suggest me to save as `nvarchar`. But I need to sort the entries according to the `datetime2` they were updated.

Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: Maybe you should add some examples and some more details. How do you "store" that date? What type is the database column?

Comment: You're trying to save the date and time to a datetime2(3) column in the database?  If so, how are you doing it?  With a standard `DataSet`, a typed dataset, a command with a dynamcally generated SQL statement and the value concatenated into the string, or a command with parameters?

Comment: @ both: I want to insert DateTime.Now in to the Sql datatype of datetime2(3). By using Fluent NHibernate I want to implement it.

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033630/datetime-precision-in-nhibernate-and-support-for-datetime2-in-nhibernate-schemee

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
var format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff";
var stringDate = DateTime.Now.ToString(format);
var convertedBack = DateTime.ParseExact(stringDate, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

DateTime is a data type representing dates and times and does not store format information.  The milliseconds are always stored in DateTime.  The only time you need to specify milliseconds is when choosing how to represent the DateTime as another type, like a string.

Comment: 6/19/2012 11:39:10 PM This is what I got as result Kevin.

Comment: When you say you "got 6/19/2012 11:39:10 PM", where do you see that value?  In the debugger?  Console?  Whatever is displaying the DateTime value is applying the formatting.  The milliseconds are still stored in the value.

Comment: Ok I got the point. I've seen it in Console. But it worked man. It got saved in Database. Thanks. I could have given u +1 but I don't have enough points. Thanks anyway.