# NHibernate truncate milliseconds from DateTime variables

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

how can I solve this problema ?
NHibernate truncate milliseconds from DateTime variables

```
DataHoraRecebimento = DateTime.Now;
DataReferencia = new DateTime(2015, 9, 8, 17, 0, 50, 332);
```

Even though I configure de LongTimePattern:

[image]

here is my configuration on hbm:

version 3.1.0.4000, 
xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2", 
MsSql2008Dialect

```
 <class name="MensagemRecebimento" table="dbo.xxx" lazy="true" dynamic-update="true">

    <id name="CodigoRecebimentoMensagem" column="COD_RECB_MSG"><generator class="identity" /></id>
    <property name="DataReferencia"><column name="DATA_REF_MSG" sql-type="datetime" not-null="true" /></property>
    <property name="DataHoraRecebimento"><column name="DTHR_RECB_MSG" sql-type="datetime" not-null="true" /></property>

  </class>
```

and here is the code that saves my object

```
NHibernateSessionHelper.Instance.GetSession().Save(obj);
```

and here is the result query that nHibernate generates after save
you can notice that the milliseconds are zeros

```
NHibernate:
    INSERT
    INTO
        dbo.xxx
        (DATA_REF_MSG, DTHR_RECB_MSG)
    VALUES
        (@p7, @p8);
    select
        SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    @p7 = 08/09/2015 17:00:50.000 [Type: DateTime (0)],
    @p8 = 19/08/2016 12:42:48.000 [Type: DateTime (0)]
```

Comment: Dates do not have patterns or locales. Patterns and locales matter *only* when converting to/from strings. Please post your query. Screenshots without code do not help at all.

Comment: without the LongTimePattern configured , the NHibernate query did not even show the zeros from milliseconds (.000), I thought it would help , but I can remove que code .

Comment: Database columns get the same values, without milliseconds.

Comment: maybe [duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033630/datetime-precision-in-nhibernate-and-support-for-datetime2-in-nhibernate-schemee)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer, I added `type="Timestamp"` to the hbm.xml

```
<class name="MensagemRecebimento" table="dbo.xxx" lazy="true" dynamic-update="true">

  <id name="CodigoRecebimentoMensagem" column="COD_RECB_MSG"> <generator class="identity" /> </id>
  <property name="DataReferencia" type="Timestamp"> <column name="DATA_REF_MSG" sql-type="datetime" not-null="true" /> </property>
  <property name="DataHoraRecebimento" type="Timestamp"> <column name="DTHR_RECB_MSG" sql-type="datetime" not-null="true" /></property>

</class>
```